# Update not working in web2py on google-appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I am building a invite module.
In the controller, I have the following code :

```
try: 
.... some initial stuff

   try:

   ... some stuff

       update_request_query = (db.INVITE_SIGNUP.email_id == request_email_id)
       db(update_request_query).update(activation_key=key,activation_url=activation_url)

   ... some other stuff

   except (Timeout,TransactionFailedError,InternalError), derr:
                logger.warn('Datastore exception for ID: '+ request_email_id +': '+ str(derr))
except (Error, Exception), ex:
        logger.error('Fatal Error: '+ request_email_id +': '+ str(ex))
```

The problem is that the update statement is not working on GAE. The fields which need to be updated are NULL and no error is thrown.
From my observation, this is happening once a day approx around the time when daily quota is reset.

Am I doing something wrong here?